# Django 1.6: MultiValueDictKeyError in dropdown form

Tags: python, django, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to implement two dropdown menus in one of my template but I keep get this error.

```
Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  57.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "views.py" in doclistings
  91.             request.session["genderselect"] = request.POST['genderselect']
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py" in __getitem__
  301.             raise MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key))

Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError at /doclistings/
Exception Value: "'genderselect'"
```

Here is a template where I'm trying to have two dropdown menus in one single form to work

```html
<form action="" method="post" >  
    <select class="form-control" id="selection" name="selection">
        <option><b>Find a Doctor...</b></option>
        {% for value, text in form.selection.field.choices %}
            <option value="{{ value }}">{{ text }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>

    <select class="form-control" id="genderdropdown" name="genderdropdown">
        <option><b>Select a Gender</b></option>
        {% for value, text in form.genderselect.field.choices %}
            <option value="{{ value }}">{{ text }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>

    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"  name="submit" id="ss-submit">Search</button>
    </span>
    </div>
    {% csrf_token %}

</form>
```

Here is the views where I'm getting the error

```
def doclistings(request):
    d = getVariables(request)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = DropdownSelectionForm(request.POST)
        print form.errors

        if form.is_valid():
            selection = form.cleaned_data['selection']
            genderselect = form.cleaned_data['genderselect']
            d['usergendselect'] = genderselect
            request.session["selection"] = request.POST['selection']

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/doclistings')
    else:
        form = DropdownSelectionForm()

    s_name = request.session.get('selection')  # Change variable name
    d['userselection'] = s_name  # Update this for new variable name
    gend = Doctor.objects.get(gender = genderselect)
    spec = Specialization.objects.get(name=s_name)  # Get spec object
    doctors = Doctor.objects.filter(specialization = spec, gender = gend).order_by('-likes')  
    d['doctors'] = doctors

    d.update({'form': form})
    return render_to_response('meddy1/doclistings.html',d)
```

Here is the Doctor model

```
class Doctor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    specialization = models.ForeignKey(Specialization)
    clinic = models.ForeignKey(Clinic)
    seekers = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='UserContent')
    gender_choices = ( ('Male', 'Male'), ('Female','Female'),)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices = gender_choices, null=True, blank = True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/', null=True, blank = True)
    mimetype = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: 99% chance it has to do with your model, can you post that too?

Comment: I've added the model above

Comment: why do you use `form.cleaned_data['genderselect']` at first and on the next line you use `request.POST['genderselect']` instead? Also what are these data in session good for?

Comment: Thanks. I got rid of that error, but now i've a new error of UnboundLocalError: local variable 'genderselect' referenced before assignment. I'm guessing my form is not validating.. Any idea why that's happening? I've changed the code above

Comment: you 'genderselect' is not defined when it reaches this line: `gend = Doctor.objects.get(gender = genderselect)` for GET requests, it will only be defined in POST requests due to the if clause.

Comment: I'm sending POST request from the form - shouldn't that work ?